# php / curl: delete cookie created with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR

Tags: php, cookies, curl

Most php / curl samples recommend creating curl cookies, and I am using one to crawl the web. 
Here is the script http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php#93163 and here is the relevant excerpt:

```
$url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
```

Now I noticed in /tmp 3 GB of curl cookie files created by php.

I was under the impression this is cleared automatically, is it possible to do this from php / curl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First `unset` the `$ch` handler, and then you should call `@unlink` command.

```
unset($ch);
unlink($cookie);
```

Comment: I had this exact same problem, and found I couldn't unlink the files.  After some experimentation, I found that curl_close($ch) had to be called before you called unlink() to delete the cookie jar file.  Perhaps unset($ch) causes the curl handle to be closed as well?

Comment: this is not clear. what to be unset ?

Comment: @Plugie This answer is for 12 years ago and I don't remember what was the problem... anyway I edited it

Answer (score -1):

You could [delete](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) the files.

Comment: But you can only delete the files after calling curl_close($ch).  Yousha Aleayoub reports in his answer that unset($ch) will also allow them to be deleted.