# how do I make cURL "delete cookies" once it executes?

Tags: php, curl

I am testing my site for cURL, and I am trying to make cURL "clear the cache", so that the session cookie will be regenerated.

So I have an index.php and a login.php. 
I do a POST to index with correct credentials and then get as expected a redirect to login.php.
Then, I try to "clear the cache" and cURL to login.php.
I am expecting to get a 302 (redirect) to index.php, but I get a 200 OK...

I am using these settings to try clear the cache:

```
$cookiefile = "d://cookie.txt";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT , 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT , 1);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php / curl: delete cookie created with CURLOPT\_COOKIEJAR in /tmp (linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474659/php-curl-delete-cookie-created-with-curlopt-cookiejar-in-tmp-linux)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to clear the cookies, you should unlink the file `unlink($cookiefile);` And after that, you can login again without the old cookie.

Good lock.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file whose name is in `$cookiefile`.

Answer (score 0):

to delete the cookies in the current curl handle, do

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, 'ALL');
```

quoting the documentation:

> A cookie string (i.e. a single line in Netscape/Mozilla format, or a regular HTTP-style Set-Cookie header) adds that single cookie to the internal cookie store. "ALL" erases all cookies held in memory. "SESS" erases all session cookies held in memory. "FLUSH" writes all known cookies to the file specified by CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR. "RELOAD" loads all cookies from the files specified by CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.